# I want jQuery to modify somethings of another page before it loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 divs. On click of any of the divs, I want to load a second page, but have some jQuery run before that page loads. The 4 .Partition are on one page, while #ContentBox1,2,3,4 are on a second page. How do I make this work? If there are other ways to do it other than javascript, I am open to all suggestions. Thanks!

```
$('.Partition').click(
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $('#ContentBox1').removeClass('active').css({ left: ($('#ContentBox1').width()) });
                    $('ContentBox' + $this.index()).addClass('active').css({ left: ($('#ContentBox1').width()) });
                }
        );
```

Comment: your description of two pages is far too loose. WHat does load another page mean to you? If it means get part or all of it to use in current page...can do that. If it means clcik a link and browser goes to new url....can't do anything with it from current page

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a page that is not loaded into the browser. The script that modifies the other page has to be included in that same page. Period.

Answer (score 0):

Load the div's from your AJAX with then set to either diplay:none or visibility:hidden, depending on your prefs. If this can't be done, add a div inside of the target div with the correct display/visibility. Use the AJAX callback to call whatever function required to modify the content, then set the display:block or visibility:visible.

Another option would be to place a div with display:none elsewhere on your page, load your content, modify the content after load. Then swap the content in the display:none div into your target div.

Comment: no need to add another element, append then remove....you can wrap an html ajax response in `$()` and do whatever you need to it there...outside of the DOM